# Why always get the same boolean value?

Tags: c++, boolean

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ( void )
{
     bool* Str_A = (bool*)calloc(1024,1);
     bool* Str_B = (bool*)calloc(1024,1);
     *Str_A = true;
     *Str_B = true;
     *(Str_A+2) = *Str_A+*Str_B;
     printf("%s", (Str_A+2)?"true":"false");
}
```

Whether I change `*Str_A` or/and `*Str_B` into `false` or not, It always print `true`.
Why?

Comment: Who says `sizeof(bool)` is definitively 1?

Comment: I tested a minute ago, really, `sizeof(bool)` is 1

Comment: You should check `*(Str_A+2)?"true":"false"`, will be still always `true` though.

Comment: Footnote 74 in the Standard: "`sizeof(bool)` is not required to be `1`."

Comment: @user2967915: On your compiler. Others might choose other sizes - the language doesn't specify the size of any fundamental types except `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
printf("%s", (Str_A+2)?"true":"false");
```

Prints `true` if the *address* of `Str_A` plus 2 is non-zero. What you want to check is if the *contents* of `Str_A` plus 2 is non-zero, so you should write:

```
printf("%s", *(Str_A+2)?"true":"false");
```

Or I would prefer:

```
printf("%s", Str_A[2]?"true":"false");
```

Answer (score 2):

In the expression `(Str_A+2)?"true":"false"`, `Str_A+2` is a pointer, since it's not a null pointer, it's converted to `true`.